# Rasterize causes black background, need white to match BioClim data

Tags: qgis, raster-conversion, rasterization

I am using the rasterize tool to convert a polygon layer into a .asc or .bil raster layer. As it is a UK study, there is a lot of sea that when rasterized, turns black. I need it to be white to match the BioClim data.

I've tried to convert using the rasterize tool, which led to the initial problem. I have then used the reproject tool to attempt to convert the data with null values of 9999, rather than 0. However, still no difference. It isn't simply a case of inverting the colour ramp either, as the actual file needs to store the data with a white background.